# how to get image full path from WP_Post Object?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get image full path so that I can apply it in the src attribute of image element.

What I am getting right now is the image, generated from function: the_post_thumbnail(); which I can't apply to image element.

What I did so far is:

```
        <?php
            $d=get_cat_ID( 'news' );
            $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$d.'&posts_per_page=1&order=DESC' );
            while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
                  the_post_thumbnail();
            endwhile;
        ?>
```

And what I want is; path of image with its name as below:

http://example.com/folder1/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/image.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get real image path of thumb image using [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src),

```
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($postId) );
$img_src_url = $img_src[0];
```

Comment: This brings the desired result: echo $img_src[0];